# Not accessing the correct package

Tags: linux-kernel, package, lib, netlink, ubuntu-19.10

I have to use `qdiscs` in some part of my project. so i was using the below command and got this error. the problem is there is libnl3 package prersent but it is searhing for libnl version.

```
nl-qdisc-add --dev=veth-host --parent=root --update plug --buffer
Error: Unable to load module "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl/cli/qdisc/plug.so": /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl/cli/qdisc/plug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262190/different-package-present-in-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu) solution mentioned in comments, but its not working. cannot comment on this link due to reputation.

I changed the 4th step to `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pkgconfigdir=/usr/local/lib`  because of some error it was giving.

It throws this error:

```
 /usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add --dev=veth-host --parent=root plug --limit=32768
/usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-3.so.200: no version information available (required by /usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add)
/usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-cli-3.so.200: no version information available (required by /usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add)
/usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-route-3.so.200: no version information available (required by /usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add)
Error: Unable to load module "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl/cli/qdisc/plug.so": /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl/cli/qdisc/plug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using the system ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Are you setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point the binary to the libraries in /usr/local/lib?

Comment: Yes I'm. I've exactly followed the steps mentioned in the link.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Ubuntu 19.10. When running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/sbin/nl-qdisc-add --dev=eth0 --parent=root plug --limit=32768` the `plug.so` is found as expected.